# ¿Cómo puedo saber si una variable es de tipo string?

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber con que puedo comparar un *string* para determinar si es un *string*.

```
function contarCaracteres(cadenaDeTexto) {
    if (cadenaDeTexto !== String) {
        cadenaDeTexto.toString();
}
```

Esta comparación no me resulta. ¿Con que puedo comparar un *string* para saber si verdaderamente es un *string*?

```js
let caracterArray = [];

function countCaracter(input) {
    if (isNaN(input) !== true) {
        //If is a number the output is false
        isAString = input.toString();

        for (let i = 0; i < isAString.length; i++) {
            caracterArray.push(isAString[i]);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            caracterArray.push(input[i]);
        }   
    }

    console.log(caracterArray);
}

let a = 'Christian';
let b = 456090;

//countCaracter(a);
countCaracter(b);
```

Comment: Podrías usar **typeof** de la siguiente forma `typeof cadena === 'string'`. Saludos ;)

Comment: Depende, ¿directamente cualquier *string* o algún ejemplo específico?, por que según el caso puede ser que `typeof` no sea lo que buscas y en cambio ocupes una *regex*

Comment: Gracias. Me sirvió utilizar typeof. También pensé en utilizar isNaN

Comment: @ChristianDOOR _isNaN_ te dice si algo es _NaN_, en este caso un string y _NaN_ no son equivalentes y el problema iba a persistir

Comment: Si me funciona al menos en mi caso. Pues quería decirle si no es número haz esto. Si es un número haz esto.

Typeof me da exactamente el mismo resultado. Pero no lo pensé porque no sabía que se podía utilizar así

Comment: Acabo de agregar la función que quería hacer. Pensando en que la idea es contar los caracteres. Entonces si el usuario ingresa un número ese número se parsea a un string y puede ser iterado. Si me pueden dar un consejo para optimizarlo, estaría agradecido

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usa [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/typeof) para obtener el tipo de un elemento

```js
function contarCaracteres(cadenaDeTexto) {
    if (typeof cadenaDeTexto !== "string") {
        cadenaDeTexto.toString();
    }
}
```

A continuación, algunos ejemplos:

```js
console.log(typeof "this is a tring");
console.log(typeof 4);
console.log(typeof []);
console.log(typeof {});
console.log(typeof null);
console.log(typeof undefined);
```